# Java Double NaN comparison for sort

Tags: java, double, nan, comparator

I'm implementing **Comparator** for a class and while overriding the **compare**, i have a question.

```
double data1 = GetValueOf(Data1);
double data2 = GetValueOf(Data2);
int compareResult = Double.compare(data1, data2);
```

What happens if data1 and/or data2 are NaN?

Is this still a valid comparison to perform?

**UPDATE**
I don't understand why this question is being down rated. Just to explain myself, I'm facing a "[Comparison method violates general contract](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7173464)" problem.

I'm doing this...

```
if(Double.isNaN(data1)) data1 = Double.Positive_Infinity;
if(Double.isNaN(data2)) data2 = Double.Positive_Infinity;
```

before the Double.compare but still getting this error.

So, I need to understand if there's some basic thing I'm not understanding.

Comment: Did you read the Java language specification to find the answer?

Comment: If you are overriding the `compare()` From `Comparator` You and only you are responsible to validate and compare data.Technology is not responsible **IF** any invalid data found during comparison raised a `Exception`

Comment: @JimGarrison, I did check the java docs but I wanted an opinion on using the Double.compare.

Comment: Did you read the Javadocs for [Double.compare](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare-double-double-) and [Double.compareTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compareTo-java.lang.Double-), which it references? Whether the NaN handling works for you is something only you can determine, based on the requirements of your data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An unordered result is result is returned if you are comparing NAN with itself.
The Java [document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/typesValues.html) says:

> An operation that overflows produces a signed infinity, an operation
>   that underflows produces a denormalized value or a signed zero, and an
>   operation that has no mathematically definite result produces NaN. All
>   numeric operations with NaN as an operand produce NaN as a result. As
>   has already been described, NaN is unordered, so a numeric comparison
>   operation involving one or two NaNs returns false and any !=
>   comparison involving NaN returns true, including x!=x when x is NaN.